# 64 bit support building Ipa with vs-mda-remote

Tags: ios, cordova, 64-bit, ipa, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to build an Ipa with 64 bit support using **Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova** (CTP 3.0) but without success.

It seems that the *vs-mda-remote* agent builds just with the Arm architecture support.
Unzipping the Ipa and checking the binary with the *file* command, returns this result:

```
Mach-O executable arm
```

The curious thing is that opening the xcode project deployed  to  the mac builder machine, the build settings of the universal architecture are properly set and building and archiving it generates an Ipa that contains a binary that supports the 64 bit architecture.

Do you know why there's this difference?
Could be some parameters that *vs-mda-remote* sets to the command line when building the project, overriding the project's build settings?
Could be a Cordova problem?

Comment: 64 bit support is included in Cordova builds since v3.4.1.  vs-mda-remote simply does a base cordova build, so you should be getting arm, arm7v, and arm64 in one fat binary. Are you encountering issues with a device or store upload? http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/25/ios-64bit.html

Comment: I found that building in Release mode creates a fat binary but not in debug mode. Is it by design?

Comment: Right now the Cordova project only builds "active architectures" under the debug config while it builds all for release. Building one speeds up build times.  Is this causing an issue?  Here's the project file: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Comment: Also, note that you should be able override this by placing a custom build-debug.xcconfig in res/native/ios/cordova with the key ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO;  Here's the original: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig

Comment: Not a problem, after I switched to release mode. Note: we have not released the app yet, so I was just investigating if our app was ok for the store. Please, consider to answer the question with the provided info in these comments, I will accept the answer and it will be a reference for other developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64 bit support is included in Cordova builds since v3.4.1, so every version of Tools for Apache Cordova has had 64-bit support. vs-mda-remote simply does a base cordova build, so you should be getting arm, arm7v, and arm64 in one fat binary when building under release.

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/25/ios-64bit.html

However, right now the Cordova project only builds "active architectures" under the debug config while it builds all for release. Building only one speeds up build times during debugging.

If you don't like this debug behavior, you should be able override this by placing a custom build-debug.xcconfig in res/native/ios/cordova with the key ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO;

Here's the original: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/scripts/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig